# Почему в мобильной версии меню закрывается и сразу открывается?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, joomla

Почему в мобильной версии меню закрывается и сразу открывается? То же самое с табами в центре.

Сайт http://tiger-light.ru

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите проблемную верстку в тело вопроса. В случае если ваш сайт заработает, проблема как–таковая исчезнет, как результат, вопрос потеряет ценность для сообщества.

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом уберите повторную загрузку jQuery. Сейчас в `<head>` стоит:

```
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

а перед `</body>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Попробуйте закомментировать или удалить строчку перед `</body>`. С большой вероятностью этого окажется достаточно.